# Finding father of node in Binary Tree converted from General Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I am using the Binary Tree implementation of a General Tree, with the general algorithm that, the first son of a node is the "left" and any other siblings are the "right" of the first son.

What I'm trying to answer is, given a node p, how can I find the father of node p?

Here is a node (I'm traversing using a non-recursive way, thus the visited and parent attributes)

```
struct node {
  std::string name;
  int sons;
  bool visited;
  node * first;
  node * next;
  node * parent;    
};
```

Here is an example:

**GeneralTree**

```
  A                   
 /|\       
B C D
```

**BinaryTree version of GeneralTree**

```
  A
 /
B
 \
  C
   \
    D
```

So the father node of B, C, and D are all A.

Comment: Your tree is very patriarchal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the parent links until you find a null reference - this happens if you start with `p` being the root node - or a node with the node you are coming from as its left child.

```
var current = p;
var parent = current.parent;

while ((parent != null) && (current != parent.left))
{
    current = parent;
    parent = current.parent;
}
```

Now `parent` contains the parent node of the node in `p` or `null` if `p`contains the root node.

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly (at least when I drew it out), now Im going to implement it